# Is there a way to edit columns in CSV file with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm trying to standardize data in a large CSV file. I want to replace a string "Greek" with a different string "Q35497" but only in a single column (I don't want to replace every instance of the word "Greek" to "Q35497" in every column but just in a column named "P407"). This is what I have so far

`data_frame = pd.read_csv('/data.csv') data_frame["P407"] = data_frame['P407'].astype(str)  data_frame["P407"].str.replace('Greek', 'Q35497')`

But what this does is just create a single column "P407" with a list of strings (such as 'Q35497') and I can't append it to the whole csv table.

I tried using DataFrame.replace

`data_frame = data_frame.replace( #to_replace={"P407":{'Greek':'Q35497'}}, #inplace=True #)`

But this just creates an empty set. I also can't figure out why data_frame["P407"] creates a separate series that cannot be added to the original csv file.

Comment: I guess you only missed to override the old value: Could you Please try `data_frame = pd.read_csv('/data.csv')` and `data_frame["P407"]=data_frame["P407"].str.replace('Greek', 'Q35497')`

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct but you have missing to store the modified dataframe.

```
data_frame = pd.read_csv('/data.csv')
data_frame["P407"] = data_frame["P407"].str.replace('Greek', 'Q35497')
```